# Scanning Code-128 barcodes issue in iOS (AVFoundation)

Tags: ios, avfoundation, barcode, barcode-scanner, code128

I'm working on adding new barcode scanning functionality to my application. Decided to use `AVFoundation` for that purposes. Implemented everything as in many examples on the Internet.

In `metadataObjectTypes` indicated only one `AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code` type that I needed.
Everything looks good and I can even scan barcodes if they have a solid background, for example, if you take and print a label with a Code-128 barcode and put it on a white sheet of paper. But if you put a printed label with a Code-128 barcode on a table with a wood-like color (I am attaching a photo), then it becomes much more difficult for the scanner to read the barcode, you have to zoom in and focus the scanner, and it takes a long time to recognize the barcode.

It is noteworthy that if I also specify `AVMetadataObjectTypeInterleaved2of5Code` type of barcodes, then their scanner scans much faster under the same conditions with the background.

Perhaps someone faced a similar problem? Maybe I'm missing some additional settings for `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` or something else?
I would be grateful for any information and help in solving this problem.

[image]

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this article](https://apprize.best/apple/barcodes/4.html) (it's not mine ... found via serching) -- particularly the section titled: **3.2.7. Tweaking capture device settings**

Comment: @DonMag, thank you so much! Going to read this article and play with capture device settings tomorrow.

Comment: Played with configs but unfortunately the same result :(